Cannot find a locally registered MBean from a local JMX client
I'm developing 2 Java applications using OpenJDK 22.0.1
The first one creates 2 MBeans using the JMX API and registers them in the local JMX server by using a MBeanServer declared like this:
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
The first MBean is registered using an ObjectName created through it's constructor by passing the following String as parameter: cl.maraneda.jmx:type=Hello.
The second MBean is an MXBean created the same way as the first one, but the String used to create an ObjectName is cl.maraneda.jmx:type=QueueSampler
The MBeans are being recognized correctly from the jconsole, I can execute it's operations correctly and, if I put the following line of code, it will show the domain I created (cl.maraneda.jmx) among other domains currently recognized by the JMX Server:
Arrays.stream(mbs.getDomains()).forEach(System.out::println);
The second application tries to connect to the same JMX Server as the first one by using an MBeanServer that is declared in the same way as in the first application.
The connection is successful, but I cannot find my MBeans through it and, if I execute the same line as above to show all domains in the second application, my domain is not present.
This is the main class of the first application:
package cl.maraneda.jmx;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

import javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException;
import javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

public class JMXDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(); 
        ObjectName name;
        ObjectName mxname;
        try {
            Hello mbean = new Hello(); 
            String strObName = 
                String.format("%s:type=%s",
                              Hello.class.getPackageName(),
                              Hello.class.getSimpleName());
            String strObMXName =
                String.format("%s:type=%s", 
                              QueueSampler.class.getPackageName(),
                              QueueSampler.class.getSimpleName());
            System.out.println(strObMXName); //It shows cl.maraneda.jmx:type=QueueSampler
            name = new ObjectName(strObName);
            mxname = new ObjectName(strObMXName);
            
            mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name); 
            
            Queue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10); 
            queue.add("Request-1"); 
            queue.add("Request-2"); 
            queue.add("Request-3"); 
            QueueSampler mxbean = new QueueSampler(queue); 
            
            mbs.registerMBean(mxbean, mxname);
            
            Arrays.stream(mbs.getDomains()).forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(mbs.toString());
            System.out.println("Waiting forever...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*Handle exception*/
        } 
         
        while(true) { /* NOTHING */ }
    }
}

And this is the main class of the second application:
public class JMXClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MBeanServerConnection mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        String strObName ="cl.maraneda.jmx:type=QueueSampler";
        ObjectName name;
        try {
            Arrays.stream(mbs.getDomains()).forEach(System.out::println);
            name = new ObjectName(strObName);
            CompositeData queueSample = (CompositeData) mbs.getAttribute(name, "QueueSample"); 
            int size = (Integer) queueSample.get("size");
            System.out.println("El tamano obtenido es " + size);
        } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstanceNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AttributeNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ReflectionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MBeanException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

SOLVED
I asked among my partners in the company I'm working on and they told me that creating an MBeanServer by using ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(); in both applications is useless because each time you call this method, you create a separate instance of the JMX server
In order to allow your MBean and MXBean objects to be accessed from JMX client applications, you must follow these steps:

Execute the application (using your OS format) that generates the MBeans and/or MXBeans (in my case, the application JMXDemo) by adding the following JVM options:

$JDK_HOME/bin/java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$PORT\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=$AUTH_FLAG\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=$SSL_FLAG\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$PORT\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=$PASSWD_FILE\
-jar JMXDemo.jar

Where
$HOST: The IP or DNS of the JMX host. For local JMX as in my case, you must use the IP 127.0.0.1 or the DNS localhost
$PORT: The port you want to use for the remote connection with JMX. There is no default port.
$AUTH_FLAG: true if you want to force users to authenticate using a username and a password; false if you want the MBeans and MXBeans to be accessed without authentication.
$SSL_FLAG: true if you want the remote connections to JMX to be through SSL; false otherwise. For Production environments, this option must always be true.
$PASSWD_FILE: The .password file containing one username and one password per line and both must be separated by a blank space. The com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file option and it's value are required if and only if $AUTH_FLAG is true. Otherwise, you must omit this option.

In the second application, you must replace this line of code:

ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
By something like this:
String host = "..."; // Replace ... with the value of $HOST
int port = 0; // Replace 0 with the value of $PORT
String strurl = String.format("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://%s:%d/jmxrmi", host, port);
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(strurl);
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection mbs = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

I hope this to be of any help to anyone who wants to work with JMX.
